# Is there a way, in PySide to style the tab buttons on a QtabWidget?

Tags: python, css, qt, styles, pyside

is there a way in PySide to style the tab buttons on the QtabWidget? I'm right now trying to make a costum styled widget, and I've styled every other element, but I can't seem to figure out how to style the QtabWidget...

I was trying:

```
self.tabWidget = QtGui.QtabWidget(Form)
self.tabWidget.tab.setStyleSheet("some style goes here")
```

but I now know I cant reference the tab like that. any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`QTabBar::tab`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#tab-sub) subcontrol.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QTabBar::tab {
                color: #FF0000;
            }
        """)

        for tabNumber in range(3):
            widget = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            widget.setText("This is widget #{0}".format(tabNumber))

            self.addTab(widget, "Tab {0}".format(tabNumber))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you... but this seems to be for Qt not Pyside... what I mean is... is there a way to use this in PySide or PyQt4?

Comment: It's stylesheet syntax, checkout my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15590320/1006989), I added a code example